# Materials to shield light in NUV-MIR range with high permeability to alpha, beta and gamma radiations

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation

I'm looking for an effective way to shield light in the class range from *NUV* (Near ultraviolet) to *MIR* (Mid infrared) especially in $430 \text {nm}$ to $1100 \text {nm}$ wavelength range, 
but letting pass *alpha*, *beta* and *gamma* radiations as much as possible.

Suggestions?

Comment: Gamma is easy (unless very low energy gammas). Minimizing mass per unit area is key for alphas and betas. I’d suggest trying very thin aluminized Mylar foils.

Comment: @JonCuster I know that for gamma is easier since it has a very strong capability to pass through matter but the problem is that I need to let pass also the others beta and alpha (the most likely to be shielded by light screen).

Comment: Hence the aluminized Mylar. Lightweight but blocks light. But it will have a cutoff energy brow which either alpha or beta will be blocked. I assume turning off the lights doesn’t work for some reason?

Comment: Yep, turning off light is not a viable option :D

Comment: For alpha and beta, how about using an ultrawide bandgap diode? Finding a pin diode with a thick layer likely is hard though. Do you need energy resolution or just counts?

Comment: I need also energy resolution. I don't know any diode with a bandgap large enough to serve this purpose unshielded. Not mentioning that a PIN diode with a thick enough layer to be light insensitive, is likely to shield "out of box" radiations as well invalidating the original purpose.

Comment: Well, you want the $i$ layer thick to catch all the charge generation from the alpha/beta like in a regular detector. I’d need a lot more info on what you are trying to do, but you could/should add that to the question.

Comment: I'm prototyping a solid-state sensor to measure alpha beta and gamma radiations based on a matrix of photodiodes.